# How to add ng-click to @Html.TextBoxFor in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor, html-helper

How can I give my TextBox, `ng-click` attribute when using `Html.TextBoxFor`?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.User.Firstname, 
new { 
    @class = "form-control required", 
    placeholder = "نام" 
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add ng_click to `htmlAttributes` object.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.User.Firstname, new 
{ 
  @class = "form-control required", 
  placeholder = "نام" , 
  ng_click = "yourFunc()" 
})
```

> *Note : The `_` instead of `-` in *ng_click* is because C# does not accept `-`